# Transformer Inefficiency and Heat

Tags: transformer

If a transformer has efficiency of 96%. It means for a 500W capacity and load, the input would be 520W, output 500W so 20W would be emitted as heat.  If load is 250W, then input would be 260W and 10 watts would be emitted as heat.

But if there is no load (zero load), how do you compute the wattage that would be lost as heat during the initial stage when magnetic field and flux is being built with no load on the secondary? Is it more than the inefficient percentage lost with load?

I'm computing sealed enclosure heat transfer for a design I'm having and I need to know the above.

Comment: If you know the inductance and the resistance of the transformer (on the primary side) then you can easily calculate that information.

Comment: The efficiency metric would normally be measured at a particular load (e.g., maximum load). From there you could estimate the equivalent resistance of the transformer. You will also need the inductance to be able to calculate the no-load losses.

Answer (score 6):

Transformers are not rated by "efficiency", they are rated by losses, although the efficiency at maximum load can be defined. So you cannot assume that at 250W of load the transformer will dissipate 10W if at max load (500W) it dissipates 20W, it will dissipate more than 10W. This is because [transformers have two types of losses](https://www.copper.org/environment/sustainable-energy/transformers/education/trans_losses.html), "load losses", and "no-load losses". Even at zero load a transformer will run warm.

Load losses depend on wire resistance of coils, and are proportional to load.

No-load losses are independent of load, they occur due to continuous magnetizing and de-magnetizing of transformer core, with two basic mechanisms - hysteresis losses, and eddy losses. These losses depend on quality of core construction and materials. To reduce eddy losses, the cores are made of thin sheets, so the eddies can't spread over much of core volume. Hysteresis losses depend of magnetic alloy composition. Some portion of magnetic field escapes the core and induces eddy currents and warm up surrounding conductors (mounting hardware, bolts and brackets), which also adds to no-load losses. Without knowing precise details of core construction and manufacturer's data, you can't "compute" these losses. For example, cheap knock-off transformers for Christmas decorations can stay pretty warm even when the lights are off.

ADDITION: I happen to have an old 200 VA auto-transformer 115:230V, model SU-38, made by TODD SYSTEMS. In idle (no load) mode, with ambient of ~25C and sitting on a pack of papers, its core gets to ~40C, see the thermal image.:

[image]

Comment: For this Hammond 172D 500VA 230v-115v step down isolation transformer. https://www.hammfg.com/files/parts/pdf/172D.pdf   I'm measuring 50 Celsius surface temperature at 30 Celsius ambient temperature. What kind of core or magnetic alloy do Hammond uses? For the most premium small isolated transformer. Can you measure just say 35 Celsius surface temperature at no-load?

Comment: @Samzun, are you measuring 50C at no load? Or what?

Comment: yes, I am measuring 45-50Celsius at no load. What is the normal or for efficient brand?

Comment: In the Hammond, the difference between zero load and half full load is only about 3 C (surface temperature)? How accurate are temperature in estimating core and winding temperature? And at full load, does it become like 10 C difference (based on actual tests of other brands)? From estimate, at half load, do you have maybe 80% of losses already compared to full load since it's not 50%? I need to know this because I'm estimating the heat emitted by the transformer at half load compared to full load. So if it's not half, then maybe 80%, typically?

Comment: @Samzun, as I said, no-load loss is impossible to calculate, there is no "typical". You do have the transformer at hands, why don't you apply a known load and measure the total power using, say, "KillAwatt" tool, and answer all your detailed questions?

Comment: My transformer input is 240v. The KillAwatt tool available only measure 120v. Anyway. Please share your own measurements of losses (or others you have seen) so I see example of losses at zero load, at half load, and at full load. I know different models would have different losses. I just want to see examples of actual tests.

Comment: @Samzun, I don't have the KillAwatt at the moment. Overall, this area is one of fundamental chapters of electrical engineering, and was in development for 150 years. Please use Google for "no-load  transformer losses", I am sure there will be some materials about the subject.

Comment: Based on experience. For say a 500VA transformer at working load, can you estimate in percentage how much are the overall losses of the iron core and winding? Id like to get estimate how much percentage increase in my electric bills by using the transformer versus not using it..do you think bills can reach 50% additional or just 10%? What are the ranges in the industry for 500VA or so? Thanks.

Comment: @Samzun, I don't know. I haven't use transformers for power supplies for the past 25 years. Maybe only as isolation transformers for some debug, but I was never interested in their losses, they just work, some like oo-oo-oo-oo-.. when fully loaded. Sorry.

Comment: What do you use for power supplies then if you don't use transformers?  Well for your measured 40 Celsius surface temperature with 25 Celsius ambient temperature above. Do you think 4 watt is enough to cause 40 Celsius surface temperature? (4 watt core loss is just highest estimate from your 200VA transformer with say efficiency of 95% and noting winding load loss are always much greater than iron loss.)

Comment: @Samzun, I can't solve heat-transfer equations of a hot cube in open air convection in my head. I lost my grip on heat transfer theories long time ago, sorry. I am sure there must be engineering formulas for this kind of simple geometry in natural convection. For power supplies I use standard SMPS.

Comment: I will buy a 240v KillAwatt tomorrow as I just learnt where to get it locally. So if the transformer has no load and I put the KillAwatt to between the ac source and the transformer input.. then whatever is the wattage being read is the no-load loss wattage, right? I wonder about this because above you stated that to test no-load loss, I had to apply a known load and measure the total power.. why do I have to apply a known load and not just use no load?

Comment: @Samzun, "no-load" is also a known load of zero. It also qualifies.

Comment: I just tested it. With no load, the wattage is 19.9Watts.. https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/640x480q90/923/CJNLT6.jpg For efficiency of 96% of this 500VA Hammond model mentioned earlier. It's right on mark. But note it's only for no-load.. which is only iron loss. If there is load, then the efficiency would be maybe just 80%? Is this typical of other models too where the reported efficiency is only for no-load and not actually the total load.

Answer (score 3):

There are two main loss mechanisms in transformers

a) Core losses, which are dependent on the input voltage

b) Copper losses, which are dependent on the load current

Designing a transformer to be low loss is a compromise between these two. In applications where the transformer may spend most of its time at no load, it's worth designing for low core loss, at the expense of high copper loss, by using a low core flux and a lot of turns.

Unless the transformer has a very thorough data sheet giving you losses at several loadings, it's not possible to *compute* the loss at any loading, it must be measured.

Comment: How about application the opposite or where the transformer may spend most of its time at near full load? Then it means design for bigger core (high core flux) and fewer turns?  What kind of core that has zero loss almost like superconducting material?

Comment: @Samzun, if you want to start designing your own transformer, here is a good place to start: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Electronics/Transformer_Design

Comment: Before I design one. I need to know what is the best core alloy material in the world that is almost equal to a superconducting wire. I want to use this core so at no-load, the losses would be minimal..

Comment: @Ale..chenski Oh boy, is that wikibooks article a mess. I wouldn't know where to start to clean it up, it needs a total rewrite. I mean, it's not actually wrong, it's that it's just not clear enough to guide a newbie into the design process properly.

Comment: It's not useless link.. there I learnt  the best core material in the world was called Vanadium-cobalt-iron core. Where can you buy 500Va transformer that uses it? I want to compare it with the Hammond to see if the temperature would become much lower (maybe just a few degree above room temperature). Of course I need to actually compare actual stuff before I even think of designing my own.. but my focus is really the circuits connected to these transformers.

Comment: Guys. I need to know important. Is it the core or the winding part that can produce bigger magnetic field? Because I need a transformer with low magnetic field. I can measure 100 milligauss at 16 inches away from it. I need magnetic field to be lowest.. So should I use less core and more winding? It's ok if the winding loss be more more and heat would be more as long as magnetic field would be much lesser. And if winding can produce more magnetic field, then bigger core and less windings to produce very low magnetic field? I need it to have lowest magnetic field for some sensitive application.

Comment: @Samzun Put that external field information in your question. A low field in the core can help reduce radiated field, especially if it's harmonics of the drive frequency resulting from field saturation. For low external field, as well as field well below saturation, you want a uniformly-wound toroidal core, and a mumetal shield round the whole transformer.

Comment: I'll write separate question about it tomorrow. I just realized from your reply and others that you can adjust core and windings design to suit the application so thought if it could lower the magnetic field. And I think this is more important than the heat which I can fix by using some fan or blower.

Comment: @Samzun The core field is only linearly important, you would would not have a very useful transformer if you tried to reduce external field by core field weakening. A uniformly wound toroidal core is very important, worth a couple of orders of magnitude over Es and Is, and an order of magnitude over an unevenly would toroid. A mumetal shield can reduce the external field a few orders of magnitude further.

Comment: What do you mean by "Es" and "Is"?  Hmm.. I want to see first a commercially available one. Can you give an existing transformer brand which has uniformly wound toroidal core and mumetal shield for low magnetic field output?  By the way, the primary and secondary windings without the core would only produce minimal magnetic field (how many percentage estimate?) and it is the core that contribute major share of it?

Answer (score 1):

Transformers are rated in VA rather than W, where V and A are RMS. VA and W are the same only for a resistive load. There is loss in the windings due to the load current, as I squared times R. There is loss in the core due to eddy currents and hysteresis loss. Core loss does not change appreciably with load.There is also some loss in the copper due to the magnetising current. I presume you are talking about a mains frequency transformer. Other factors apply at higher frequencies.

Comment: All "other factors" you've stated also applied for mains transformers of 50/60Hz  especially when the power ratings are in KVA ranges.

Comment: I was thinking of skin depth and proximity effect. Given that the skin depth in copper is about 9 mm at 50 Hz and the questioner gave a 500 VA transformer as an example, I didn't want to add detail that wouldn't really be applicable to him/her. Perhaps I should have said these factors are not significant at mains frequencies at the power level asked about.